# How do you handle auto-renewable subscriptions in apps that have a non-Apple account system?

Tags: ios, app-store, storekit

I am working on an app that provides users with the ability to sign in and out using accounts on my service. I also want to provide users with the ability to purchase auto-renewable subscriptions.

I can't figure out how to enable users to sign in and out using accounts on my service and purchase auto-renewable subscriptions. This is because StoreKit purchases are tied to the device's logged in Apple ID, and cannot be tied to accounts on my system.

For example, suppose:

- A person has an iPhone and is signed in to iOS on that device using their Apple ID: `bob@icloud.com`
- This person downloads my app, and creates `userA` in my account system.
- As `userA`, they buy an auto-renewable subscription. This purchase is stored on the StoreKit receipt for user `bob@icloud.com`.
- Without changing Apple IDs, the person signs out my app and creates `userB` on my system.
- The person tries to buy the same auto-renewable subscription for `userB`. When they do this nothing happens. Specifically, [this code](https://github.com/j3k0/cordova-plugin-purchase/blob/857e7daefaac3475d29cfe97c5df356b79633764/src/ios/InAppPurchase.m#L371-L401):

```
SKMutablePayment *payment = [SKMutablePayment paymentWithProduct:[self.products objectForKey:identifier]];
//...
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];
```

does not prompt `userB` to purchase, because as far as StoreKit is concerned, they already own it, because they are still `bob@icloud.com` on the device.

**Even if I store subscription information on my servers (which I do), I'm not sure how I can remedy the situation except for allowing only Apple Sign In on the iOS version of my app.** This is because Apple Sign In is strictly tied to the current Apple ID on the device.

Is this really the only way to have users in an app that also has IAP auto-renewable subscriptions? I've [searched the web](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/96696) and it seems like that's the case.

Comment: Subscriptions are limited to 1 in each group for an Apple ID. If you have multiple user account they won't be able to make seperate purchases unless they are from different Apple IDs.

Comment: Thanks. So, basically, the only way to do user accounts on an app that has subscriptions is to use Apple Sign In? That way app sign in is the same as phone sign in.

Comment: No you don't have to use Apple Sign in. If you use your sign up system. You will need to store receipt for logged in user. Like saying user A is now subscribed. That does create complications on restore. If user B tries to restore purchase, that should not work and you will need to communicate to user why.

Comment: Using Apple Sign In would simplify restore. If your product supports multiple platform then you will still need to save receipt for user and of course support Apple sign in on all platforms.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm still not sure I understand: Say user A signs in with my app's login system, creates an auto-renewable subscription (with the logged in Apple ID), then signs out. Then user B signs in with my app's login system. Even if I stored user A's subscription status on my server, when user B tries to make a subscription, it will still be the same Apple ID locally on the phone (that never changes) so StoreKit will not let user B subscribe. Is that correct?

Comment: I am focused on auto-renewable subscriptions specifically.

Comment: @DmitryMinkovsky - there's only one way around this!  see answer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***IF I understand***, what you want to do is:

• on YOUR system there are TWO users, A and B

• in reality, A and B are the same person.  (Call her "Jane".)

• in fact Jane has (obviously) the same iPhone, whether she is your-system-A or your-system-B.  Let's refer to that iPhone as iPhone 7778636728637

• you are offering a subscription named "dragon-eggs-renewable"

So:

When 7778636728637 wants to buy "dragon-eggs-renewable",

you want to be able to sell her

• "dragon-eggs-renewable" for A

AND sell her

• "dragon-eggs-renewable" for B

## That is totally impossible.

The subscription "dragon-eggs-renewable" goes only *by the phone*.

Sign-on-with-Apple is unrelated. <sup>†</sup>

Subscriptions go *by the phone* and that's it.

## But there is a way around this:

The trick is. Have say ***three*** subscriptions named,

- "dragon-eggs-renewable"
- "dragon-eggs-renewable-supp1"
- "dragon-eggs-renewable-supp2"

In your system, if they are user A, sell them "dragon-eggs-renewable".

However, if you realize they are user B, **sell them "dragon-eggs-renewable-supp1"**

You see what I mean?

It's not at all unusual to sell more than one subscription.  (Example "powerup1" ... "powerup2" ... etc)

Hope it works, and hope I understood!

Unless there is something new in late 2020 regarding sign-on-with-Apple, the above is the situation!

Comment: Thanks. I see what you mean. That is what I was suspecting and basically just wanted confirmation that this is the case (I added a link to the end of my question that seems to support this). I appreciate your hack but I don't think I would implement it just because it seems more trouble than it's worth; really too complicated for me to do something like that at this time. So cleanest the way to go is to only support Apple Sign In on my app? That way there is a strict 1-to-1 relationship between Device Apple ID and my app user?